# How to handle false value in jsonarray

Tags: android, android-listview, json

In my Php file while retriving value from mysql db if there are ny row present in db its returning the correct value but when there is no row present in databse then its returning false value thriugh json_encode
My php code is:

```
 <?php

     $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     if (!$con)
       {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       mysql_select_db("meetingschedulardata", $con);

        $mdate=$_GET['mdate'];
    //$mdate= '28-April-2013';  
        $date = strtotime($mdate);
    $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $date);


       $sql=mysql_query("select * from meetingdetails where mdate='$new_date'",$con);
    $row=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($row===0)
    {
        $output[][]=false;
        print(json_encode($output));
    }
    else
    {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
            $output[][]=$row;
        print(json_encode($output));
    }


        mysql_close();

?>
```

My java code where im parsing json value is:

```
try{

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/meetingschedular/viewdetail.php?mdate="+currentDateandTime);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Convert response to string
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();                 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //END Convert response to string

            try
            {               
                JSONArray jArray =  new JSONArray(result);

                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                    {   
                        JSONArray innerJsonArray = jArray.getJSONArray(i);
                        JSONObject json_data = innerJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);                     
                        String at= json_data.getString("attendees"); 
                        String at1=json_data.getString("title");                    
                        String at2=json_data.getString("mtime");
                        String at3=json_data.getString("venue");
                        s.append(j+"Attendees:"+at);
                        s.append("\nTitle:"+at1);
                        s1.append("Time:"+at2);
                        s1.append("\nVenue:"+at3);

                        r.add(s.toString());
                        r.add(s1.toString());
                        j++;
                    }

                l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, r));

            }

            catch(Exception e1)
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

I am not getting how will i handle if json_encode return false value and show some toast in response to the false value. Pls help me. :(

Comment: what do you meant by false value?

Comment: false value that we are getting from the php page....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the insertion of false within your php code, remove the if block, and simply allow an empty json to be sent. You seem to have set up an appropriate catch block to handle your Toast message.

Comment: Ya but i want to display another msg not the exception.. how will i do that?